# Select Multiple Values From Single Column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to select multiple values from a single column in a database table that equal to a number of values. I want all these values to match otherwise it should return no rows. I do not want to use "IN" as that is equal to "OR".

The following is a basic mockup of what it should do **but it needs to be dynamic** as I wish to use it with a PDO statement. If the database only contains id's 1 and 2 it should fail ie return no rows.

```
SELECT
id
FROM
reports
WHERE
id=1 AND id=2 AND id=3
```

I have the current code as follow which is incorrectly returning zero rows:

```
SELECT id,title
FROM reports
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY title 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 2
```

My current table structure is as follows:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce4aa/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `HAVING COUNT(id) = 3` to ensure that the selected rows have all the three id's. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 -- Or id IN(1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY SomeOtherField
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3;
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE SomeOtherField IN (SELECT SomeOtherField 
                         FROM reports
                         WHERE id = 1 or id = 2 -- Or id IN(1, 2, 3)
                         GROUP BY SomeOtherField
                         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3
                        );
```

**Note that:** You have to `GROUP BY SomeOtherField` where `SomeOtherField` is other field than `id` because if you `GROUP BY id` with `HAVING COUNT(id)` you won't get any records, since `COUNT(id)` will be always = 1.

**Edit:** fixed `WHERE` clause, `OR`'s instead of `AND`'s.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18969/4)

Comment: @Nuvolari Can you please show me the table structure and some sample data? note that you have to `GROUP BY` other field than that `id` becuase if you `GROUP BY id` this won't give you nothing since `COUNT(id)` will be 1 always  since you are grouping by it.

Comment: @Nuvolari Sorry, it should be `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 ` or `WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3)` instead of `WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2 AND id = 3` like my updated answer.

Comment: @Nuvolari is the `title` is unique for each `id`? Can you please post the table structure? it would help, thanks.

Comment: @Nuvolari But, there are no reports titles that had all the `report_id` 1, 2, 3 in that sample data. This assuming that you are looking for those titles that had all the report_id's 1, 2, 3. Is this really what you are looking for? Also what the right output from that table that you are looking for? Thanks.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal I updated the table with more data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce4aa/1 I am just looking to see whether the query returns rows or no rows and do something based upon that.

Comment: @Nuvolari - What is the output that you are looking for from that table?

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal I am testing it via rowCount() to see whether it returns some rows or no rows in an if statement in PHP.

Comment: @Nuvolari OK, but which `id` and `title` the query should return for the sample data in the fiddle demo?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter I just want to count the rows returned but basically if I do where id IN (1,2) the query should return 2 rows if correct or zero if it didn't find one or none of the id's.

Comment: @Nuvolari So how about `SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE report_id IN (1,2);` like in [**this updated demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce4aa/4), this will give you two rows. But, this won't ensure that the selected data have all the ids 1, 2.

Comment: No I need it to be equivalent to id=1 AND id=2. It should return zero rows if both of those conditions are not met.

Comment: @Nuvolari So, you are looking for those titles that has the both `1` and `2` in the same time? something like [**in this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fffc/3)? if not what is the exact output from this query for example? and how a row should have the two conditions `id = 1` and `id = 2` in the same time?

Comment: Ok thx that did it but I have this weird error where I have the exact same table with same setup just different name and its returning zero rows. I have checked it over its 100% the same and has same data in it but gives me different result.

Comment: @Nuvolari - Can you please setup a sql fiddle demo for that explaining the issue? Feel free to ask again if you need any thing else.

Comment: Hi I found the issue. The query only works if there are duplicate titles. Ie two titles with the same text. Compare: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76ccc/2 which has all different titles with http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fffc/3 which has a duplicate

Comment: @Nuvolari Yes, thats right. As I said before, the query I wrote will give you those titles that has both the ids 1 and 2. In case of [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76ccc/2) there are no titles has both 1 and 2 so the query is correct. Isn't that correct?

Comment: No but look at the fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76ccc/2 it does have 1 and 2 for id:  (1, "report 1"),(2, "report 2").  No rows are being found though when they should be.

Comment: @Nuvolari OK, but they haven't the same title. In this case [`SELECT *
FROM reports1
WHERE report_id IN (1,2)`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76ccc/4) will work fine for you. Because `report 1` has only 1 and `report 2` has only 2. There are no rows has the both the ids in the same time. What are the rows in the table that has both the ids 1 and 2? none.

Comment: "Report 1" has an ID of 1 and "Report 2" has an ID of 2. Using that query you suggested won't work as it will work if only 1 of the two is found.

Comment: @Nuvolari - No, this [`SELECT * FROM reports1 WHERE report_id IN (1,2)`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6890d/1) will give you the one of them that found for example report 1

Comment: I have found a solution to this via using some more PHP. He's what I mean: http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=50fc14888214b My only problem now is why I can't use :query_string in the IN () spot. If I do it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nuvolari It is just doing `SELECT * FROM reports1 WHERE report_id IN (1,2)` try to print the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try following.

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
GROUP BY SomeOtherField
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3
and id IN(1, 2, 3)
```